# SQLite - Why wasn't this thrown as a syntax error?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I just spent the last hour trying to figure out why my SQLite database wasnt updating.

The query being done was

```
UPDATE Table SET col1 = val AND col2 = val2 AND col3 = val3 WHERE col1 = val4
```

Obviously this is the wrong syntax for an update query, however no exceptions were thrown, no errors shown and when run directly using [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org) it even said that the query executed correctly and had updated a row (yet no update was done)

Can anyone explain why this query wasn't rejected with an exception or syntax error?

**Update:**

So after looking at things further, I can see that an update was indeed performed, however instead of setting `col1` to the new value, it was instead set to 0 which seems odd.

Comment: Question: Would the `WHERE` clause have even allowed any records to be updated, had the rest of the syntax been legitimate?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, as once I had fixed my stupid mistake the query works correctly

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This was part of a sync method that retrieves the newly created ID in a remote database after a new record was generated, then updates the local database with the new ID based on the old (temporary) local id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AND operator in most languages, including SQLite, can be used in expressions (for boolean or bitwise operations, etc.), and the `=` operators is testing for equality, so you're just setting `col1` equal to the value of the expression `val AND col2 = val2 AND col3 = val3`.

For example, if all the columns and values are 1 in your expression, you're setting col1 to:

```
1 AND 1 = 1 AND 1 = 1
```

...which is a valid expression that evaluates to 1.

SQLite will report as many rows as matched by the `WHERE` clause to have been affected by the update, *even if the new value in `col1` was the same as the old value*, i.e. even if the data isn't actually changing. It still found rows to update and put a new value in there, so it reports having successfully performed an update.

We'd need to know the types/values of the columns to work out exactly what's going on, but I don't see a syntax error there, though it's clear you didn't mean to do what the expression (validly!) says!

Comment: Yes but why was no `UPDATE` performed then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the `UPDATE` updated `col1` to its existing value, SQLite will still say a row was updated, but no apparent update will have happened.

Comment: Upvoted.  Just curious if other weirdness was happening assuming the `WHERE` clause would have allowed any updates.

Comment: val4 is different to val1, so i would have expected col1 to have updated (which didnt happen) - even if it ignored col2 and 3. So im curious as to why that update was ignored

Comment: @Takarii It might not have been ignored. You said SQLite told you a row was updated; my guess would be that the value in `col1` was already equal to the value of your boolean expression. SQLite would still report the row being updated, but the value in `col1` would be the same as it was before, so it'll *look* unchanged. Remember you're setting `col1` to the value `val AND col2 = val2 AND col3 = val3`, whatever *that* works out as.

Comment: Sorry, I missed something. An update was indeed performed, however I didn't see it as the rowid was already zero. When checking it again, i see the update did indeed happen however it set the id to 0. So now im curious why that result happened

Comment: @Takarii I think you may still not be understanding what's going on. Your statement sets the value of `col1` to the result of the boolean expression `val AND col2 = val2 AND col3 = val3`. That is, it will only set `col1` to 1 if `val` is 1 and the values of `col2` and `val2` are the same, and the values of `col3` and `val3` are the same. (i.e. you're calculating `val is true AND (col2 = val2) AND (col3 = val3)`)

Comment: I understand now, and naturally the column it then applies to is the one mentioned in val4. (so in the case of what I was doing, it would indeed return 0)